# How to play, pause and stop a song with only one button?

Tags: android

I have tried to make an application in android to play, pause and stop a song with one button only.

Can anyone show me how can I make that application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Button bPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
            MediaPlayer song1 = MediaPlayer.create(tutorialFour.this, R.raw.fluet);
        Button bStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStop);
        bPlay.setWidth(10);
        song1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                bPlay.setText("Play");


            }
        });
        bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b=true;

                if(bPlay.getText().equals("Play") && b==true)
                {

                    song1.start();

                    bPlay.setText("Pause");
                    b=false;
                }

                else if(bPlay.getText().equals("Pause"))
                {
                    x=song1.getCurrentPosition();
                    song1.pause();
                    bPlay.setText("Resume");
                    Log.v("log",""+x);
                    b=false;
                }
                else if(bPlay.getText().equals("Resume") && b==true)
                {
                    song1.seekTo(x);
                    song1.start();
                    bPlay.setText("Pause");
                    b=false;
                }


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

With one button, the idea, I would guess, can be as follows:

- Keep a boolean indicating whether the playback is active at the moment; set it to true when you start playback, and false when you stop/pause it or it completes.
- On a regular tap of the button, if no playback is active, then start the playback
- On a regular tap, if playback is active, then pause it
- On a long tap, if playback is active, stop it

Answer (score 0):

click once to toggle between play/pause.
double click for stop.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the reference for the button at onClickListenerObject, you may call setOnClickListener in there.