# Change button in layout

Tags: android

I am currently working on a `Music Player`. In layout I have a `Play` button. When I press the `Play` button The audio start playing. It's not the problem. The problem is When I press the `Play` button I want to show a `pause` Button instead of `play` button. But How can I change the `play` and `pause` button??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658942/how-to-play-pause-and-stop-a-song-with-only-one-button

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onPlayPress(){
    //start music
    playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

So your Play button will be hidden and Pause button will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

try this code.

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
            } else {
                // Resume song
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.puse);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

On play button's click event you can do something like this.

```
playbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pauseimage);
```

You have to just change the layout of button.And you can do it vise-varsa.